# How to say "about" as in "to read about"

Tags: grammar, nuances, word-requests

I wonder how to say something like

> Now I'm reading about ways to get to Kyoto from Tokyo.

I know the necessary words but I wonder how to say this "about". Will it be okay if I just write this?

> 今、東京から京都まで行く方法について読んでいます

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your sentence is grammatically correct. について is a good way to say "about" in many situations. However, in this case I think it would be more natural to say

> 今、東京から京都まで行く方法**を調べて**います。
>   I'm [ looking up / reading about ] how to get from Tokyo to Kyoto.

調べる is often translated to "investigate, examine", but it's a very common word and I think "look up, read about" are equally valid translations.

について読む sounds a bit like you are reading, say, a monograph on historical travel routes.